# Whether the fiber of a holomorphic covering of the unit disk over a non-simply-connected domain is infinite or not

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

Consider a holomorphic covering $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \Omega$. Then for any point $a$ in the domain $\Omega$, consider the fiber $f^{-1}(a)$. If $f$ is non-constant, I know that when $\Omega$ is a simply connected domain, then $f$ is a homeomorphism, thus the fiber consists of only $1$ point. But what if $\Omega$ is not simply connected? Is it true in general that the fiber is infinite?

Comment: Do you still require $\Omega$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (as opposed to, say, a genus two Riemann surface)?

Comment: @Michael Are you claiming that there is a counterexample in that context? Please note that my ignorance regarding Riemann surfaces is truly profound. But that said, look at the second argument in my answer. Seems to me it shows that if $f$ is a covering map from the disk to anything whatever, if $f$ has enough holomorphicity to ensure that the deck transformations are holomorphic then the fibers must be infinite. ???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: No, the fibre is still infinite in that case. I just asked as the OP didn't say what $\Omega$ was (aside from not simply connected).

Comment: @user220124 Hold everything. In fact this is true for any covering map $f:\mathbb D\to X$, holomorphic or not. Edited reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiber has to be infinite. [EDIT: In fact this has nothing to do with holomorphicity. See below.] Top-of-head argument and then one after I opened a book:

Say $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $\Omega$ which is not null-homotopic. Say $\gamma^n$ is "$\gamma$ repeated $n$ times" (sorry, I don't know this stuff). Then $\gamma^n$ is also not null-homotopic for $n>1$.

Say $\Gamma_1$ is a lift of $\gamma$, say starting at $z_0\in\mathbb D$ and ending at $z_1$. Say $\Gamma_2$ is a lift starting at $z_1$ and ending at $z_2$. And so on.

The points $z_0, z_1, \dots$ must all be distinct, hence the fiber is infinite.

They must be distinct. Suppose otoh $z_4=z_2$. Then $\Gamma_3+\Gamma_4$ is a closed curve in the disk, which is null-homotopic. But $\Gamma_j$ is a lift of $\gamma$, hence $\Gamma_3+\Gamma_4$ is a lift of $\gamma^2$; now applying $f$ shows that $\gamma^2$ is null-homotopic in $\Omega$.

Surely there's a better way to put all that in terms of homotopy groups and deck transformations and things. But it seems right...

---

Ok, I cheated and opened a book. A slightly more grownup version of more or less the same argument: Since $\Omega$ is not simply connected the "covering group" or group of "deck transformations" is non-trivial. Say $\phi$ is a non-trivial element of that group. On general topological grounds $\phi$ cannot have a fixed point. So $\phi$ is parabolic or hyperbolic; equivalent to either a translation or dilation in the upper half-plane. Hence the orbit of any point under $\phi$ is infinite.

---

In fact this has nothing to do with holomorphicity. Say $f:\mathbb D\to X$ is any non-trivial covering map. As before there exists a non-trivial deck transformation $\phi$. Except now $\phi$ is just a homeomorphism of the disk. Being a non-trivial deck transformation, $\phi$ has no fixed point. And the orbit of any point under $\phi$ is infinite: If the orbit of some point is finite then there exists $n$ so that $\phi^n$ has a fixed point. Since $\phi^n$ is a deck transformation this implies that $\phi^n$ is the identity. And I'm told that there is no homeomorphism of the disk with finite order but no fixed point; see [Homeomorphisms of the Open Disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337910/homeomorphisms-of-the-open-disk/1337954#1337954) .